# How is a subquery with join in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table that has two relationship with other table but the same field.

For example:

`first_user_in_comment_id & last_user_in_comment_id`

so these fields has relation with the name user `name_user`

My laravel version is 5.5

```
 $conseguirTabla = DB::table('ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS')   
        ->JOIN('CICLOS_ESCOLARES','CICLOS_ESCOLARES.ID','=','ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.CICLO_ID')
        ->JOIN('USUARIOS','USUARIOS.ID','=','ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.USUARIO_ID')
       ->JOIN('USUARIOS','USUARIOS.ID','=','ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.USUARIO_MODIFICACION_ID')
            ->SELECT('USUARIOS.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE', 
                    'CICLOS_ESCOLARES.CICLO_ESCOLAR AS CICLO_ESCOLAR',
                    'ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.FECHA_COMENTARIO AS FECHA_COMENTARIO',
                    'ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.COMENTARIO AS COMENTARIO',
                    'ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.USUARIO_MODIFICACION_ID AS MODIFICACION'
            )   

            ->WHERE('ALUMNO_ID',$idAlumno)         
            ->get();
```

Comment: evidently two join in the same table shouldnt exist

Comment: That's not completely true there are [self joins](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-self-join.php). Anyway what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DB::raw for example:

```
       ->JOIN(\DB::raw('USUARIOS as x'),'x.ID','=','ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.USUARIO_MODIFICACION_ID')
       ->JOIN(\DB::raw('(select * from USUARIOS) as y'),'y.ID','=','ALUMNOS_HISTORIAL_COMENTARIOS.USUARIO_MODIFICACION_ID')
```

Comment: i dont understan very good, May you pass me the complete code block?

Comment: The first line is that I'm just adding  alias to table and second one is using sub query in join